# Heat Kernel Asymptotics with low regularity

Tags: riemannian-geometry, heat-equation, asymptotics

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with Riemannian metric $g$, which is not smooth but only continuous.

**Question:** Is there still an asymptotic expansion of the heat kernel of the form
$$ p_t(x, y) \sim (4 \pi t)^{-n/2} e^{-\frac{1}{4t}d(x, y)^2}\sum_{j=0}^\infty t^j \Phi_j(x, y)$$
where the correction terms $\Phi_j$ are only continuous (or some other regularity that makes sense)?

**Assume the following "mild form" of irregularity of $g$:** Assume $g$ is smooth everywhere except at a submanifold $N$, where it is still smooth in direction of $N$ and only non-smooth in directions transversal to $N$, but maybe still Lipschitz-continuous.

Answer (score 5):

The Varadhan's asymptotics

$t \ln p_t(x,y) \to_{t \to 0} -\frac{d^2(x,y)}{4}$

is known to hold in Lipschitz Riemannian manifolds. It was proved by James Norris in his paper:

Heat kernel asymptotics and the distance function in Lipschitz Riemannian manifolds, Acta Mathematica, Volume 179, Issue 1, pp 79-103

This Varadhan's asymptotics was later generalized by K.T. Sturm,  [J. Math. Pures Appl. 75 (1996), 273–297] and Ramirez  [Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 54 (2001), 259–293] to even more singular spaces.

Concerning the full  Minakshisundaram–Pleijel expansion for the heat kernel on singular spaces, I am not aware of general results. This is still an active domain of research.  There is an interesting example that I like, that comes  from a measurable Riemannian structure on the Sierpinski gasket. See for instance the short summary

[Measurable Riemannian structure and its heat kernel analysis on the Sierpinski gasket](https://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/probability/sympo/sa10/kajino.pdf)

It shows that weird and interesting things can happen.